# Ruby browser automation

Tags: ruby, macos, automation, ruby-1.9

I want to write ruby script which run browser (for example, firefox), open web-addresses, click links, check/uncheck boxes and other stuff. What gem can i use for that?

Comment: Did you try typing the title of this question into google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) / [Selenium Ruby](http://selenium.rubyforge.org/getting-started.html) is another option and there's [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) for scripting Firefox.

> "It is implemented as a Firefox extension, and allows you to record,
>   edit, and debug tests."

Answer (score 1):

Check watir and watir_webdriver which is used for automated web browser testing but it can be used for browser scripting from ruby http://watir.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the rb-appscript framework to automate macosx

http://appscript.sourceforge.net/rb-appscript/index.html

Its a ruby framework that uses the applescript interfaces to interact with the macos applications.

I'm not sure if there is a gem you can use to install yet but there is are install instructions in the link above.

there is a nice article at http://www.apeth.com/rbappscript/00intro.html that shows how to replace applescript with ruby using rb-appscript

Answer (score 0):

Check out watir, watir-webdriver or firewatir. It's very easy to use especially if you're just starting out. You can check out this quick tutorial on how to set it up, it's extremely easy.

http://webmites.org/watir-automated-tests-for-everyone/